# Bash manage space separated list

Tags: bash, array, data

I have a rather complex shell script which processes several list of values which are read from a file as space separated values e.g.

```
SET1="value1 value2 value3"

for i in ${SET1}; do
   ...
```

I now want to create a similarly formatted list in the script to write out. However if I do (for example) this:

```
DISCOVERED=''
DISCOVERED+=( us-east-1 )
DISCOVERED+=( us-east-2 )
DISCOVERED+=( us-west-1 )
for REGION in ${DISCOVERED} ; do
    echo $REGION
done
```

I get no output. I do get output if I specify `in ${DISCOVERED[@]}`. It appears I am working with different data types in SET1 and DISCOVERED.

I can easily append to a string with space-separated values, but I end up with either a leading or trailing space which needs cleaned up:

```
function append_discovered {
   local VALUE="$1"
   if [ -z "${DISCOVERED}" ] ; then
      DISCOVERED="$VALUE"
   else
      DISCOVERED="${DISCOVERED} ${VALUE}"
   fi
}
```

....but this seems rather cumbersome.

I could treat my output variable as an array - but then I either need to convert it back (`DISCOVERED="${DISCOVERED[@]}"`) at appropriate places to use a different construct for iterating through this list than I have for the other lists.

What is the data type for my input data (e.g. $SET1 above) if not an array?

Is there a neater way to append this list and keep the same data type?

Comment: if you're happy with using word splitting on the string (i.e. that `for REGION in ${DISCOVERED}`), then a leading or trailing space doesn't matter, it'll disappear during word splitting. So in that case, you might as well use `DISCOVERED+=" us-east-1"` etc. to append to it. But, seriously, it'd be much cleaner if you just used an array all the way, and would actually work even in the future if/when you need values that themselves contain whitespace or glob characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It appears I am working with different data types in SET1 and DISCOVERED

Indeed. `SET1` is a string. It happens that you interpret the string value as being several space-separated elements. `DISCOVERED` on the other hand is an array with several elements.

```
set1='this is a string of seven words'
discovered=('this' 'is' 'an' 'array' 'with' 'seven' 'elements')

echo "$set1"
echo "${discovered[@]}"
```

One problem with your `SET1` code at the top of your question is that each element will be globbed and expanded. So if you have a file called `onebananatwo` in your current directory and you encounter an element `one*`, the globbing will expand `one*` to become `onebananatwo`. (Preventing this is why double-quoting variables is always strongly recommended.)

> I can easily append to a string with space-separated values, but I end up with either a leading or trailing space which needs cleaned up

You can use a conditional expansion to insert the space only if the string is not empty:

```
append_discovered() {
    local value=$1
    discovered="$discovered${discovered:+ }$value"
}
```

(Notice I've removed the non-standard `function` keyword and lowercased the variable names so that they don't unexpectedly clash with reserved variables.)

Here's what's happening with `$discovered${discovered:+ }$value`:

- When `$discovered` is the empty string, `${discovered:+ }` also returns an empty string, and so the result is just `$value`
- When `$discovered` has a value, `${discovered:+ }` returns a space, and so the result is a string comprising `$discovered` and `$value` separated by a single space

Going forwards I'd recommend you consider using an array for array data types rather than space-separated elements in a string, but I appreciate that retro-fitting this into an existing script may not be cost-effective or sensible.

Comment: The variable expansion is neater than if..else - ta

Comment: ....`function` is deprecated? Not on my man page, and Google seems confused too. Got a reference for this?

Comment: @symcbean, I don't think it's deprecated in the sense of being obsolete and being phased out, but it is non-standard and unnecessary in Bash. There's a difference between `func() { ... }` and `function func { ... }` in ksh, but not in other shells AFAIK (and `function func() { ... }` is an error there).

Comment: @symcbean I've replaced _deprecated_ with _non-standard_. In hindsight that's probably a better choice or word

Answer (score 2):

In my Mac's bash 5.x your first syntax works:

```
DISCOVERED=''
DISCOVERED+=( us-east-1 )
DISCOVERED+=( us-east-2 )
DISCOVERED+=( us-west-1 )
echo ${#DISCOVERED[@]}
printf '"%s" ' "${DISCOVERED[@]}"
echo
```

The output is:

```
4
"" "us-east-1" "us-east-2" "us-west-1"
```

Perhaps you expected the `DISCOVERED=''` statement to delete all array elements instead of setting the first element to an empty string, so your attempts to expand/return the first array element made it appear the array was empty?

If you want to ensure the array variable is cleared (no elements), I suggest `DISCOVERED=()` or `unset DISCOVERED`.

*Edited to add:*

For generating a delimited string from the array elements, I usually use a simple two-liner.  This example uses '`:`' as the delimiter character:

```
printf -v SET1 '%s:' "${DISCOVERED[@]}"
SET1="${SET1%:}"
echo $SET1
```

(I didn't include the empty first array element) The output:

```
us-east-1:us-east-2:us-west-1
```

It uses a property of the built-in `printf` to iterate the array elements, appending the delimiter to each one. (Hooray, I don't have to write a loop!)  The second line removes the final delimiter.  This will also work with the space character as a delimiter, but that's easier done as `SET1="${DISCOVERED[@]}"`.  It's not very elegant having the second line to strip the last delimiter, but it works for many use cases, it's simple, quick, and doesn't call external commands.